# Can't use 'expand' on struts 2 debug browser output

Tags: java, struts2, dojo

I am working with an example application, attempting to study the debugging tools in Struts 2.  I have done the following:

- put `<s:head />` within my `<head>` tags
- put struts2-dojo-plugin in my maven dependencies
- put "?debug=browser" at the end of the link being invoked

When I click on the link that has the "?debug=browser" at the end, it displays the debug page, with a number of links labelled "Expand".  I am not getting any errors at this point in the console.  When I hover over the "Expand" links, they show "javascript://nop/"; when I click on them, I can't see that anything happens.  I tried a number of different ones.

When I look at the source for the page, I can see that there is javascript to execute when the execute link is clicked.  I attempted to enter the Chrome debugger, but I don't know how to open the source so that I can set a breakpoint.

So, does someone know something else to do that a newbie might forget?  Or can someone please point me to some kind of troubleshooting method?

Comment: well, the prefix for the tags is determined by the prefix set in the JSP tag that declares the tags; are you saying it won't work with an 's' prefix but will with an 'sx' one?

Comment: `sx` is for s2-dojo tags.

Comment: But dojo tags are deprecated, and it might not work with your browser.

Comment: The <sx:head> is in addition to the <s:head /> I have for JSP struts tags?

Comment: Ok, putting <sx:head /> into the index.jsp, where the rest of this stuff is, didn't help.

Comment: But you have a different error, right? :) See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4349.

Comment: The first is a tag from plugin, the second is a core tag.

Comment: No, same error.  @RomanC, thanks for the explanation.  Whatever it is, either it isn't helping or there's something else I need with it.

Comment: If you want to debug a javascript you can use a javascript debugger, I'm sure your browser has one or plugin like Firebug in FF. The IDE also have a javascript debugger but I never use it. You can use at least `s:debug` tag to show some variables from the action context.

Comment: yeah, as I said in the original question, my problem is that I can't open the source (in the debugger).